# Return few SQL versions / candidates using SQLDatabaseChain langchain

Tags: langchain, large-language-model, chatgpt-api, py-langchain, google-generativeai

Im using langchain library SQLDatabaseChain.from_llm to convert text to SQL, Im using the return_sql=True parameter to return the SQL query itself.
Is there a way to ask the model to return more than 1 SQL query? meaning, few options/versions?

Alternatively, is there a way to see the candidates of the model queries generated and not only the selected one (the one it returned)?